# Auto Play on HTML5 Video on iPad like BBC iPlayer?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad, html5-video

Is it possible to get HTML5 Videos to auto play on iPads?

I thought that it wasn't due to restrictions on iOS, but then I tried [**BBC iPlayer**](http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/bigscreen) on my iPad it seems like the videos do auto play when you load them.

Does this mean that it *is* possible? 
Perhaps they using some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't autoplay on iOS, playback *must* be user-initiated from a UI event handler (like a touch action or a click). See [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html). I suspect the iPlayer uses a single touch/click event handler to load the video and start playback.

Answer (score 0):

Well I know when designing for Browsers you go:

```
<video controls="controls" autoplay>
<!--source here-->
</video>
```

Well if that doesn't work try using some javascript...